# Angular2 / HTML validation stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, validation, typescript

I've been writing a web application and i've got three different forms.
I've put some validation on them but it seems that after a recent update everything gets ignored.

Validation that still works:

-checks if input isn't empty
  -Maxlength

Validation that stopped working:

-Patterns

-input type email ( This is the one that surprises me the most), it doesn't 
  check for an '@' anymore or any other checks it does if you put your input 
  type to email.

example code = `

```
  <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': submitted && (!trainer.email || emailExists)}">
    <label for="email">E-mail*</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="trainer.email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter e-mail adress" />
    <div *ngIf="submitted && !trainer.email" class="help-block">E-mail adress is required</div>
    <div *ngIf="submitted && emailExists" class="help-block">E-mail adress "{{emailInUse}}" is already in use</div>
  </div>
```

`

I've removed everything from the html and put in just a single email input type and it still doesn't work. I guess it goes wrong somewhere else in my code but I don't know where to start looking. This example is for my trainer class but I have 2 other html files that also suddenly stopped working so that adds to my conclusion that the problem isn't in the HTML.

Is there any common bug that causes these kinds of problems?

Thanks